# Is there a way to ignore a test in uTest?

Tags: scala.js, utest

For example, spec2 has a feature ["Pending until fixed"](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.HowTo.html#Pending+until+fixed).

Is there a way to ignore a test in [µTest](https://github.com/lihaoyi/utest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the way it's done so far is to comment it out. It's not great, but it's been enough for now. Perhaps such a feature may appear at a later date, but it doesn't exist right now.

Source: I wrote uTest